# json file into lua table

Tags: json, lua

How is it possible to get the input of an json file:

```
       {    "name": "John", 
            "work": "chef", 
            "age": "29", 
            "messages": [
                {
                    "msg_name": "Hello", 
                    "msg": "how_are_you"
                },
                {   "second_msg_name": "hi",
                    "msg": "fine"
                }
            ]
        }
```

into a Lua table? All json.lua scripts I found did not work for JSON with new lines. Does someone know a solution?

So piglets solution works for the string in the same script.
But how does it work with a JSON file?

```
local json = require("dkjson")

local file = io.open("C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\Lua_Plugins\\test_file_reader\\test.json", "r")

local myTable = json.decode(file)

print(myTable)
```

Here then comes the error "bad argument #1 to 'strfind' (string expected, got FILE*)" on. Does someone see my fault?

Comment: you should link the scripts you have tried and how you attempted to use them. another simple solution would be to remove line breaks from the string befor feeding them into your json.lua scripts. but it is probably a user error. any json library should deal with linebreak just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
local json = require("dkjson")

local file = io.open("C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\Lua_Plugins\\test_file_reader\\test.json", "r")
local content = file:read "*a"
file:close()
local myTable = json.decode(content)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
local json = require("dkjson")
local yourString = [[{    "name": "John", 
        "work": "chef", 
        "age": "29", 
        "messages": [
            {
                "msg_name": "Hello", 
                "msg": "how_are_you"
            },
            {   "second_msg_name": "hi",
                "msg": "fine"
            }
        ]
    }]]
local myTable = json.decode(yourString)
```

http://dkolf.de/src/dkjson-lua.fsl/home

Comment: If i test this it says "unfinished string near '",'. Did you tested it ? @Piglet

Comment: then your string is malformed. my code is ok. edit your question and add how you use the library... you're probably putting that text in quotes which is not ok

Comment: i did not know that with the quotes. Now it is working. Do you know an solution with an json file? I will edit my question.

Comment: if you use double quotes in your string you need to use something else to make it a string. for example single quotes. but short strings cannot go over multiple lines so you need to use a long literal string as shown in my example. if another question comes up you should post another question. not update your orginal one